# Match Username and Password that is fetched in database - Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I need to match my username and password that is fetch in the database. right now the problem is I cannot match the username and password like the image you see below:

[image]

here is my code below:

**HTML**

```
    <body>  
          <div class="container box">  
           <div class="form-group">  
            <h3 align="center">Live Username Available or not By using PHP Ajax Jquery</h3><br />  
            <label>Enter Username</label>  
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />


            <span id="availability"></span>
            <br /><br />
            <button type="button" name="register" class="btn btn-info" id="register" disabled>Register</button>
            <br />
           </div>  
           <br />  
           <br />  
          </div>  
  </body>
```

**jQuery script** - this is where the match availability will show after the username and password is match or mismatched

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#username, #password').blur(function(){

    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

     $.ajax({
      url:'check.php',
      method:"POST",
      data:{user_name:username, password:password},
      success:function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
       if(data != '0')
       {
        $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Username and Password not Match</span>');
        $('#register').attr("disabled", true);
       }
       else
       {
        $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Username and Password Available</span>');
        $('#register').attr("disabled", false);
       }

      }

     })

  });
 });  
</script>
```

check.php - database connection and query

```
  <?php  
    //check.php  
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "", "dbname"); 
    if(isset($_POST["user_name"], $_POST["password"]))
    {
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["user_name"]);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);
     $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You have password as plain text or crypted? If you use any framework your passwords probably will crypted and you must compare hashes instead of plain text password.

Comment: Or try change condition like this if(data !== '0')

Comment: @daremachine yes you are correct i dont use crypted or hash on this example. although my database is on hash... is that a problem???

Comment: If you see in db in column 'password' #%greg$65 and you try to compare this with plain text posted in post then  #%greg$65 is not equal to abc in your code.

Comment: @daremachine yep.. the password is hash... how can we solve this problem sir?

Comment: @daremachine can you provide code sir please? thank you

Comment: First you need to know how create that hash. In php you hash your post value and then compare hash == db_hash

Comment: @daremachine i used md5 has sir how can  i do it ? can u refer to my code please thank you

Comment: @daremachine , sir i think it will not work, i tried putting a password with no hash.. but it didnt work

Comment: echo the sql query. You will exactly know, what is happening.

Comment: @Nit this is the query `0SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = 'admin' AND password = '202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'` which is correct.. but it says it is not match

Comment: Which number returns ??? `SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = 'admin' AND password = '202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'`

Comment: check my answer!

Comment: @Nit , where's your answer sir?

Comment: try to put your html code inside form tag

Comment: @Nit , that will not help as i use ajax

Comment: can you please tell us what is your data type of password field in Database and are you sure you are using md5

Comment: @Nit , yep i am sure i am using `md5` tried it on password and it worked.. but when I add username and password together it is not working

Comment: what is the length of your password field?

Comment: @Nit - 3 why is that important?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your condition is wrong in the client end script. If username and password matched then it will return value which is greater than 0 . In that case, your code should be

```
success:function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
    if(data == 0)
    {
      $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Username and Password not Match</span>');
      $('#register').attr("disabled", true);
    } 
    else
    {
      $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Username and Password Available</span>');
      $('#register').attr("disabled", false);
    }
   }
```

Comment: i have tried that a while ago.. but IDK why it worked ! thanks man it is amazing

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"])) 
    {     
 $username = $_POST["username"]; 
 $password = $_POST["password"]; 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM admin WHERE username = '".$username."' AND  password = '".$password."'");
 $result=$connect->query($query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
        { 
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
            $_SESSION["username"] = $name; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'The username or password are incorrect!';
        }
}
```

Comment: does not work sir, do you think it is on the script code?

Answer (score -1):

> **FOR MINUS POINTS** This is a solution to the problem that the OP also had. Please see main thread comments. Thank you.

Just wrap your POST value into [md5 function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php).

```
$password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]));
```

**OR** can try use [MD5 in database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = MD5('".$password."') ";
```

Then password hash should be equal to database hash.

Comment: i tried it sir but as I also tried inserting password with no hash into my table.. it also didnt work but thumbs up for your idea.

Comment: I updated answer.

Comment: it still does not work here is the query looks like `0SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = 'admin' AND password = MD5('202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70')`

Comment: or is it in the script code??? do you think the problem is on the script code?

Comment: no you create hash twice.. use first php approach OR second by db query. You create hash from hash now.